# C# Threading Wonders

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-phone-7

Lets say you would like to add items to a data structure in C# asynchronously.

So the typical step by step procedure would usually follow:

```
List1.add(variable1); 

List2.add(variable2);

List3.add(variable3);
```

..etc.

Is it possible to do this asynchronously?

I will say also say there are no dependencies between each list or it's respective variable.

Can this be done nicely?

Comment: Yes, you can do it. You will only get into troubles when there is only *one* list that is populated by *several* threads.

Comment: Do you have several lists or one shared list for all the threads?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I will say also say there are no dependencies between each list or it's respective variable.
>   Can this be done nicely?

Yes, as long as each thread has its own list there is no problem a all.

And a simple way to do it:

```
Parallel.Invoke(
   () => List1.add(variable1), 
   () => List2.add(variable2),
   () => List3.add(variable3)
);
```

On the other hand, `List<>.Add()` is a pretty small and fast method so you won't see much benefit of doing this. There's only a gain when 2+ lists need to grow internally at the same time. And there are better ways to deal with that.

Comment: +1 for the first mention of 'you won't see much benefit of doing this'.  If the item being added is small, eg. a pointer/reference, I would expect that the benefit would be negative.  If the item is large, it probably should have been added as a pointer/reference anyway <g>.

Comment: @MartinJames - I think it's more about the interanl re-allocation. `Add()` is usually O(1) but sometimes O(n)

Comment: I don't know how the internal storage extends itself - maybe it doubles each time it runs out, maybe the realloc then needs a copy, don't know.  Still doesn't seem like a good candidate for concurrency, with all the thread signaling going on, scheduling/dispatching threads etc.  I suspect that three pool threads would get shoved onto three cores just to shift three vars, (possibly just ints/pointers/refs), into lists :((

Comment: I appreciate this Henk!  I believe the class Parallel does not exist for WP7.  Any idea on how to go about it on WP7?

Comment: @Ryan - you should have tagged it as WP7 , makes a lot of difference. Note that you should probably forget about it in this particular case. Otherwise, look at the Phone.Reactive stuff. Not my department.

Comment: @Henk, I added the tag to the question.  I'll look into the Phone.Reactive stuff.